# Client side validation not working for items in a list

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

My ASP.NET Core web app (v7.0 - Uses the VS template) has a Razor page for individually editing a list of people. The page contains a table and each row is for a single person. The row contains a form element and includes the person's property values and an Update button. (The page template iterates through the person list using an index number instead of foreach so that the binding sends the new properties when Update is clicked.)

I've added validation but I can't get the client side validation to display a message when the input element looses focus. For example, An invalid year of birth value.

I've tried using the @Html methods (TextBoxFor, ValidationMessageFor etc) and just defining the HTML elements directly (An input with asp-for set and a span with asp-validation-for) but neither way works.

The Razor page model class:

```
public class PersonListModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Person> PersonList { get; set; }
}
```

The class for the list item:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1900, 9999)] 
    public int YearOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

The template for the Razor page:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Year of Birth</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for(int index = 0; index < Model.PersonList.Count; index++)
        {
            <form id="form-@index" method="post">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PersonList[index].Id)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonList[index].FullName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonList[index].YearOfBirth)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Update" asp-page-handler="UpdatePerson" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonList[index].YearOfBirth)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you added the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts? They are used to display error messages for form inputs fields.

Comment: Based on property attributes like `[Required]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but it seems to only happen when the form is loaded in the table.

If I do not apply table, for example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @for (int index = 0; index < Model.PersonList.Count; index++)
        {
            <form asp-page-handler="UpdatePerson">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.PersonList[index].Id" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@Model.PersonList[index].Id" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.PersonList[index].Id" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.PersonList[index].FullName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@Model.PersonList[index].FullName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.PersonList[index].FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.PersonList[index].YearOfBirth" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="@Model.PersonList[index].YearOfBirth" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.PersonList[index].YearOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        }
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

When I enter wrong data, then make it lose focus:
[image]

If you need to use table, you can use `onblur` event:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Year of Birth</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int index = 0; index < Model.PersonList.Count; index++)
        {
            <form id="form-@index" method="post" asp-page-handler="UpdatePerson">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.PersonList[index].Id" type="hidden" />
                            <input asp-for="@Model.PersonList[index].FullName" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.PersonList[index].YearOfBirth" onblur="checkNum(this)"  />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.PersonList[index].YearOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
     
    <script>
        function checkNum(value) {
            var Num = value.value;
            if(Num < 1900 || Num > 9999)
            {
                value.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('td')[3].append('The field YearOfBirth must be between 1900 and 9999.');
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

Test Result:
[image]